# Clutch pedal has become very soft and engages very late

Tags: clutch

I own a 2010 hyundai i20. The problem is the clutch pedal in my car has become very soft and it engages the gear when the clutch pedal has almost been released, previously it used to engage when it was released half way. Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple candidates that come to mind are:

- Air in clutch line.  Bleed clutch lines.
- Failing master or slave cylinder.  Inspect, replace as necessary (and bleed clutch lines afterwards).

Comment: thanx a lot i will get them tested.

Comment: I saw a case years ago where a slipping clutch was heating up the transmission so much that it ended up boiling the fluid in the clutch hydraulic lines!  Boiled hydraulic fluid is a very bad thing, doesn't do it's job very well.  Sometimes transmission issues can be tricky to diagnose and fix.  If you're really new to cars, I'd have to recommend having a shop look at it, and they might even find it challenging.  Could be very frustrating to work on yourself.  You're best served by starting with simple things like filters, oil changes, brakes, etc.

Comment: what could be the cause of the heating of the fluid? I usually tend to give too much gas while picking up mostly on uphills when I am unsure and sometimes get nervous. Do you think this could be the reason and also i drive my car only once a week that too for an hour or two(rarely long drives) .

Comment: It would be fairly hard to do unless you already had a mechanical fault.

Comment: hey buddy sorry for the delay. the problem was with master cylinder as you suggested.. got it replaced.. :)